# What is the role of ‘zur’ in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, german-to-english, preposition

I’m trying to understand the following sentence (the bit in bold is what I’m struggling with):

> *Schon bei diesem ersten Anprall wären weniger erfahrene und tapfere Seeleute als die der „Argo“ zweifellos **zur einen Hälfte** über Bord gespült worden und **zur anderen** in Ohnmacht gefallen.*

I think this means (more or less):

> *Already by this first impact half of a crew that was less experienced and brave than the crew of the ‘Argo’ would undoubtedly have been washed overboard, and the others have fainted.*

I don’t really understand the function of the ‘zur’ though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preposition *zu* can, among many other uses, be employed to restrict a statement to some fraction of the agents being mentioned:

> Die Besucher waren schon abgereist. (The visitors had already departed.)
>   Die Besucher waren *zu drei Vierteln* schon abgereist. (*Three quarters of* the visitors had already departed.)

Similarly *zur Hälfte*, *zu 37 Prozent*, *zu einem großen Teil/zu einem Großteil*, etc. I think there is no way to express this in the same way in English; instead, you need to change the subject as in the example above, or to add a suitable adverb: The visitors had *mostly* ...

Answer (score 2):

#### Zur einen / zur anderen Häfte

In German this expression is used for *one or the other part of a half*, the preposition *"zur"* being a contraction of *"zu der [Gen.]"* here.

In your context we may then translate it to

> ...[one] half of the sailors went overboard whereas the other half fainted.